# How do the ePhoto and Cowboy Studio beauty dishes compare for a newbie learning the ropes?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting, flash, diy

I'm wanting to buy a beauty dish and I'm on a tight budget, I can't find reviews comparing the ePhoto vs Cowboy Studio Beauty Dishes and was hoping one of you might help me choose.

I'm looking at these two to start off:

[ePhoto Beauty Strobe A120 Bracket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003D681Q8)
or 
[Cowboy Studio Strobie Bracket Strobist Photographic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003M5R9HM)

I want one to hook onto my Canon 580ex speedlight on location since I don't have a way to port my lights around outside yet (no portable power).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that you are on a tight budget, so I am going to suggest a different route and build your own dish.  I used [this](http://davidtejada.blogspot.com/2008/04/beauty-dish-for-sb-800.html) tutorial written by David Tejada and **made my own beauty dish** for I believe **under $20**. Works fantastic, and since it cost so little, if you are unhappy with the results, you could then look into spending more money on a pre-fabricated model. It took me under and hour from start to finish to create it, and no special tools.

Comment: +1 Those two products are the same, but if you're on a budget, @dpollitt's suggestion is great!

Comment: Thank you!! I'm going to get the stuff today and try it.

Comment: @RKennedy - Glad you are going to try the DIY route, its fun and it works well! Feel free to click the checkbox next to this answer if you feel it is the "best" answer from those provided!

Answer (score 0):

You can see example of the light quality of ephoto 16" dish here on
[flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/lumodi/4182365215/in/photostream/lightbox/).

Full disclosure: I shot this as comparison to test improvements we made to our own dishes.

Comment: Hi Brandon. This does not really answer the specific question posed, which asked for an explicit comparison between ePhoto and Cowboy Studio dishes. If you have additional photos that demonstrate the difference, and can explain how those differences matter to a novice, your question would be more acceptable.